# Converting epoch time to NSDate - result is wrong

Tags: objective-c, epoch

I am getting epoch time in a json string, the time is coming in as:

1374493503000

I'm using the following code to convert the time:

```
//convert time since epoch to date
                NSString* strTime = [dictThisEarthquakeProperties objectForKey:@"time"];
                NSTimeInterval seconds = [strTime doubleValue];
                NSDate* epochNSDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
                NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
                NSLog (@"Epoch time %@ equates to %@", strTime, [dateFormatter stringFromDate:epochNSDate]);
```

My result is this:

```
Epoch time 1374493503000 equates to UTC 45525-12-19 14:50:00 +0000
```

Any help/explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh, nevermind, I was getting milliseconds from the json, not seconds.

Comment: Then mark it as answer and close the question

Comment: I have to wait 48 hours to accept my own answer.